# Calendar View in X2Many from field

Tags: odoo, calendarview, odoo-11

I have a form with a many2manyfield, the field is related to model (say x.y) at which I have defined both kanban and calendar view

I can successfully see both views of model `x.y` when I open records of this model

But when I look form view of an other model `x.z` (this model has relation to x.y via `my_manay2manyfield`), it shows me the kanban view (twice) in its form successfully according to following code, but shows nothing for `mode="calendar"`

```
<field name="my_manay2manyfield" mode="kanban"/>
<field name="my_manay2manyfield" mode="calendar"/>
<field name="my_manay2manyfield" mode="kanban"/>
```

Comment: show the complete record model along with  field.